# C++ goto with stringstream identifier

Tags: c++, stream, goto

How do I make a goto command using a stringstream such that the following works?

```
stringstream location;
location<<loc<<4<<3;
goto loc43;

loc43:
[goto links to here]
```

Or should I use another type of stream?

My understanding is that `location<<loc<<4<<3`; makes location contain loc34.
Then I want the goto to link to the loc43 identifier ("loc43:"). I'll have a set of them (loc33, loc53, loc21, etc.), and the 3 and 4 will be variables. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: This is not how C++ works at all. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm very confused about what you're asking about. What exactly do you think this code does? What do you think `location<<loc<<4<<3` does? And what relation does it have to `goto loc43`?

Comment: Are you trying to *dynamically* construct a `goto` label? And if so, you're hoping that this matches some pre-existing (at compile-time) label in the code? I'm very confused.

Comment: @kjikay That's exactly what I want to do. Is that possible?

Comment: @user3769181, No. I can guarantee you that using `goto` will almost never gain you any advantage in C++. In this case, it sounds like you just want functions.

Comment: @user3769181: No, it is not possible. A `goto` is interpreted at compile-time. A `stringstream` is constructed and filled at run-time instead. If you think you need this (and why do you?), then you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how C++ actually works. You are probably looking for an array/factory that contains function pointers, then you can register your functions by name strings at run-time so that you look them up and call them by name when needed.

Comment: @user3769181 You would do better to think of a problem, and how to solve it.  You are asking about this _solution_, but I don't see you mentioning any _problem_ that it might solve.

Comment: `location<<loc<<4<<3;` will not do what you want; it will give you a compile-time error message because you haven't declared `loc` (as you would know if you'd compiled your code before posting it). Identifiers exist only in your source code, not in your running program.

Comment: [This might point you in the right direction a little bit](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html). This allows you to specify a `goto` destination dynamically, but is specific to GCC.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for you is a function map. Lets put the code after `loc43` in a function called `func1()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void func1()
{
    cout << "func1" << endl;    
}
int main() {
    map<string, void (*)()> mymap;
    mymap["loc43"] = func1; //setting the function

    mymap["loc43"](); //calling the function
    return 0;
}
```

We are using a `map` with function pointers. This code will print out `func1`.

Comment: or `map<string, function<void(void)>>`

Answer (score 0):

stringstream is a string builder. If you want to get string "loc43", you should write the codes like this:`location << "loc" << 4 << 3;`
The label `loc43` in goto statement has no relationship with the string "loc43", build by stringstream.
The `loc43` in goto statement is a lable, can not be any variable.